# Is there an anticommutative counterpart to the center of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am self studying ring theory and I came upon the concept of center.

> The center of a ring $R$ is a subring $Z(R)$ such that $xy=yx$ for $x \in Z(R), y \in R$.

I am wondering if there is also a concept for the case where $xy = -yx$, i.e. an anticommutative counterpart of a center. I will appreciate references for which this case is discussed as I think this will be valuable to what I am working on for research (mathematical physics).

Comment: Just a note: unlike the center, it is not going to be a subring in general.

Comment: Certainly any ring has such an "anti-center". And it's non-empty, as it contains $0$. However, it is not in general closed under multiplication, as the product of two such elements would be in the center, not the anti-center. It may still have interesting properties, though.

Comment: If the ring is unital, that "anticentre" is contained in the set $\lbrace x\in R: 2x=0\rbrace$ (which is just $\lbrace 0\rbrace$ for many rings). If the ring has characteristic $2$ on the other hand, it equals the centre.

Comment: On the other hand, there are well-studied [anticommutative algebras](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Anti-commutative_algebra) (like exterior algebras i.e. wedge products), although one might want to give up associativity (Lie algebras). I guess you are aware of that.

Comment: The group theory equivalent is also sometimes useful. It's the collection of elements $g$ such that $g^{-1}xg=x^{\pm 1}$, rather than just $x$. I don't think anyone looks at just the $x^{-1}$ bit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a $\Bbb Z$-graded ring.
For every $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $R_n$ denote the subgroup of $R$ consisting of $0$ and all elements of degree $n$.
For every $n\in\Bbb Z$ let
$$Z_n=\{x\in R_n:\forall m\in\Bbb Z\forall y\in R_m(xy=(-1)^{nm}yx)\}$$
and $Z=\sum_nZ_n$.
Then $Z$ is a graded subring of $R$.

Comment: Does it have a name?

Comment: This is introduced in Bourbaki's Algebra without a name.